# Can we use the photochromic lens as a MOSFET?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals, electronics, electrical-engineering

So the way a MOSFET works is it has a channel through which either hole or electron current is controlled through the gate voltage making it a switch. Now a photochromic lens has changeable transmittance of visible light. When the lens is exposed to UV light because of radical formation of silver halide in silica glass the transmittance of silica is altered.

So similarly using UV light as a gate voltage and photochromic silicate glass as a channel can we make a MOSFET type of gate. This will make electronic chips faster as now the signal speed can achieve speed of light and not restricted by the electron current.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: How would a photochromic gate be faster than a MOSFET? Even modern photochromic lenses take around 15 seconds to transition. Do you know about a photochromic device that can transition in a nanosecond?

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm not sure but that transition time is when we use the lens for spectacles with that thickness and length. I think when the dimensions change to micro or nano the transition time or the reaction time is far less.

Comment: Even at that small scale, the chemical transitions between silver halide and elemental silver still takes some time. Even if you can get sufficient transitions to occur in a microsecond that's still more than a thousand times slower than electronic gates running on a system with a gigahertz clock speed.